# What is the idiomatic way of creating foldable collection out of file hierarchy?

Tags: clojure, reducers

Having a collection of files/directories I'd like to create a collection of all leaves files.
I'd like the resulting collection extend the clojure.core.protocols/CollReduce protocol.

Do I need to extend the protocol or are there helper functions for that?

In other words. Do reducers only help in parallel reduction or can I use them to effectively generate reducible collections in parallel as well?

To illustrate the problem let me show the implementation which could work, granted that the file hierarchy is no deeper than two levels (e.g our collection can contain files and directories, but the directories can contain only files)

```
(ns user
  [import [java.io File]])

(defn expand [reduction-function]
  (fn [result input]
    (if (.isFile input)
       (reduction-function result input)       
       ; if not a file we assume it's a directory
       (reduce reduction-function result (.listFiles input)))))

(defn process [xfn c]
  (lazy-seq (when-let [s (seq c)]
    (concat ((xfn #(concat %1 (list %2))) '() (first s))
      (process xfn (rest s))))))


(def f (File. "C:\\WORK"))

(process expand [f])    ; => produces list of files
```

Now, it would be nice to have the expand defined in recursion-like style (or rather as a cascade of transformations), so it works for all levels, but executed in parallel fashion. As with reducers we can define early termination in reduction, I'd like to have ability to define generation (collection expansion) which stops when certain criteria is met (reaching file in directory hierarchy tree, as in file example)

Comment: Clojure's collections are already reducible. Some are better suited for parallelism because they can be partitioned faster than linear time. Its unclear what you are wanting to do / what exactly you are asking.

Comment: I know that the clojure collections are reducible. Question is how efficiently populate data into them (in parallel fashion). As an example consider that you have on java.io.File which point to a directory. Now before you start mapping over it, we need to generate a collection holding all files in that directory, recursively. Can reducers help in that generation step?

Comment: So you are wanting to reimplement `(defn leaf-files [path] (filter #(.isFile %) (file-seq (clojure.java.io/file path))))` in parallel? Or do something in parallel on the results?

Comment: I want to generate collection in parallel but not as you have proposed. I want to reach all leaves in file hierarchy from all levels of directories. Preferably using reducers helpers if possible. So not to have deal with threads myself.

Comment: I would use a reducer on the result from file-seq as @A.Webb describes. Assumed the walking of the fs is the fast part, and the parallelized part is the action taken on each leaf. Also consider that disk IO on a single FS does not tend to get faster with parallelization - in fact the typical result when doing file ops in parallel is to get worse overall performance due to excessive time spent seeking the disk.

Comment: This is perfectly valid point. Let's step back a bit though. I have used the files example as an illustration of the problem. What I'm really interested in is how to generate collections reducers style. Ideally how to interleave generation reduction steps, to construct efficient parallel algorithms for tasks such as pagerank (without determined number of reduction steps). Think about it as a cascade of interleaved map reduce steps where map can produce more results than input collection.

Comment: Unless your filesystem is spread accross multiple disks.